# Semantics of DataFrame groupby method

Tags: python, semantics, pandas-groupby

I find the behavior of the `groupby` method on a DataFrame object unexpected.

Let me explain with an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
                   'key2': ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'],
                   'data1': np.random.randn(5),
                   'data2': np.random.randn(5)})
data1 = df['data1']

data1
# Out[14]: 
# 0    1.989430
# 1   -0.250694
# 2   -0.448550
# 3    0.776318
# 4   -1.843558
# Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

`data1` does not have the `'key1'` column anymore.
So I would expect to get an error if I applied the following operation:

```
grouped = data1.groupby(df['key1'])
```

But I don't, and I can further apply the `mean` method on `grouped` to get the expected result.

```
grouped.mean()
# Out[13]: 
# key1
# a   -0.034941
# b    0.163884
# Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

However, the above operation does create a group using the `'key1'` column of `df`.

How can this happen? Does the interpreter store information of the originating DataFrame (`df` in this case) with the created DataFrame/series (`data1` in this case)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the grouping columns are typically from the same dataframe or series, they don't have to be.

Your statement `data1.groupby(df['key1'])` is equivalent to `data1.groupby(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'])`.  In fact, you can inspect the actual groups:

```
>>> data1.groupby(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']).groups
{'a': [0, 1, 4], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

This means that your `groupby` on `data1` will have a group `a` using rows 0, 1, and 4 from `data1` and a group `b` using rows 2 and 3.

Comment: It is not same as `data1.groupby(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'])` but same as `data1.groupby(pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']))`

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time I was wrong.  Technically, you are correct.  But in this case it evaluates to the same result, no?

Comment: There are data aligned, so here yes, but if have 2 different Series is necessary align indices first.

Comment: That's my point.  You could do `data1.groupby(['a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']).sum()`, which would return a series indexed on `a` and `c` with the first value being the value from the first row from `data1` and the sum for `c` consisting of the sum of the next four values from `data1` (corresponding to the indexation of the grouping). Note that `c` does not even appear in the original dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if same df then data are aligned and all working. But I think general situtaion if Series have different indexes like - `s1 = df['key1']`
`s1.index = s1.index * 100`
`s2 = df['data1']`
`s = s2.groupby(s1).mean()`

Comment: Yes, good example to show the grouping is based on the index.  If the indices were not aligned between `data1` and `df`, I believe the equivalent functionality would be to group on the values: e.g. `data1.groupby(df['key1'].values).mean()` (which uses the fact that each have equivalent row numbers despite the index values for the rows).

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is only syntactic sugar, check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) - selection by columns (`Series`) separately:

> This is mainly syntactic sugar for the alternative and much more verbose

```
s = df['data1'].groupby(df['key1']).mean()
print (s)
key1
a    0.565292
b    0.106360
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: No problem. Only I see first was my answer accepted, so I mentioned only one answer in StackOverflow should be accepted.